# Delete row based on value in any column of the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

There are several posts on how to drop rows if *one* column in a dataframe holds a certain undesired string, but I am struggling with how to do that if I have to check *all* columns in a dataset for that string, AND if I do not know beforehand exactly which column contains the string.

Suppose:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : ['December 31,', 'December 31, 2019', 'countryB', 'countryC'],
                     'col2' : ['December 31,', 21, 19, 18],
                     'col3' : [np.NaN, 22, 23, 14]})
```

Which gives:

```
                col1          col2  col3
0       December 31,  December 31,   NaN
1  December 31, 2019            21  22.0
2           countryB            19  23.0
3           countryC            18  14.0
```

I want to delete all rows that contain **December 31,**, but not if **December 31,** is followed by a year in YYYY format. Is use a regex for that: `r'Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec(?!.*\d{4})'`, which properly identifies **December 31,** only.

The problem is that I have many of such tables, and I do not know beforehand in which column the **December 31,** (or its equivalent for other months) appears.

What I currently do is:

```
delete = pd.DataFrame(columns = data.columns)
for name, content in data.iteritems():
    take = data[data[name].astype(str).str.contains(r'Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec(?!.*\d{4})',
                                regex = True,
                                flags = re.IGNORECASE & re.DOTALL, na = False)]
    delete = delete.append(take)
delete = delete.drop_duplicates()
index = mean(delete.index)
clean = data.drop([index])
```

Which returns, as desired:

```
                col1 col2  col3
1  December 31, 2019   21  22.0
2           countryB   19  23.0
3           countryC   18  14.0
```

That is, I loop over all columns in **data**, store in **delete** the rows that I want to delete from **data**, delete duplicates (because **December 31,** appears in col1 and col2), get the index of the unique undesired row (0 here) and then delete that row in **data** based on the index. It does work, but that seems like a cumbersome way of achieving this.

I am wondering: Is there a better way of deleting all rows in which **December 31,** appears in *any* column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.DataFrame.any(...)`

```py
mask = data.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(r'Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec(?!.*\d{4})',
               regex = True, flags = re.IGNORECASE & re.DOTALL, na = False)).any(axis=1)

data.loc[~mask]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data[~data.apply(lambda x: any([True if re.match('December 31,$',str(y)) else False for y in x]), axis=1)]
```

- You can use `.apply` method to filter rows like this.
- Doesn't using `r"December 31,$"'` regex works for your case? `$` represent ending of string. If not just replace regex with your working regex.