# Delete row based on value in ANY column of the dataframe (R)

Tags: r

I have the same problem as posted e.g. here:
[Delete row based on value in any column of the dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58879714/delete-row-based-on-value-in-any-column-of-the-dataframe#)
but would appreciate a solution in R. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is `filter_at` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    filter_at(vars(col1, col2),  all_vars(!str_detect(., "December 31,$")))
#               col1 col2 col3
#1 December 31, 2019   21   22
#2          countryB   19   23
#3          countryC   18   14
```

---

Or in `base R` with `Reduce` and `grep`

```
df1[!Reduce(`|`, lapply(df1[c('col1', 'col2')], grepl,
          pattern = "December 31,$")),]
#               col1 col2 col3
#2 December 31, 2019   21   22
#3          countryB   19   23
#4          countryC   18   14
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col1 = c("December 31,", "December 31, 2019", 
"countryB", "countryC"), col2 = c("December 31,", "21", "19", 
"18"), col3 = c(NA, 22, 23, 14)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, many thanks for different options!